# How to get cookies from browers to use in electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron

Sharing cookies from the browser to the electron app

I log in to my website. Then I start my electron application. I don't want to log in. I need cookies or tokens to log in. Is it possible to share cookies from the browser to the electron app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about this from a security perspective: If any app could read any of the Browser's cookies, then it would be simple to spy on users or impersonate them from the outside (a malicious app, like spyware or something similar). So the answer is "maybe".

Firefox, for example, stores the cookies (assuming that you have not set a primary password for your profile) in an SQLite database in a well-defined folder. So you could definitely try to read them.

However, AFAIK most antivirus software is aware that this is a security problem and will thus nuke any app other than the browser which tries to access them.

So, as long as no antivirus software is installed and Firefox is used without a primary password, you "should be good".

However, this is not a good idea, even from a user perspective: The connection between "I logged in via my browser" and "I am logged in in the app" is not intuitively clear. Also, some (most) users may consider this a breach of trust. After all, if you read their cookies, what else will you read? Who guarantees that you only use the cookies from your particular webpage? An app "randomly" reading your cookies is kind of creepy if you think about it.

Then there's another hurdle to overcome: How do you decide which of the multiple browsers installed on the system (and even if uninstalled, there probably will still be the users' profiles left) is the "right" one? What do you do if multiple browsers have multiple session cookies for your webpage? All this is not as easy as it might seem in the first place.

I suggest you to look into some other technologies, like OAuth2, which may reduce the "login process" inside your app to a single click in case there's a session open for the device. How this is implemented specifically is out of scope for this answer (and hard to explain and understand without the required basic knowledge).